# How to open a photo with python for use in an API post request

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I am trying to open a test photo in python to upload the photo using the imgur API.  I have found guides online with how to do this using javascript but am trying to learn python so help in that language would be appreciated.

The error i'm getting is

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\media\\test.jpg'
```

I suspect that the cause of the error is with my pathing to the `test.jpg` file but I can't seem to figure out the right way to get to that file.  I have uploaded my sample code below and it is also in the github post linked [HERE](https://github.com/kevinlowen1/NASA_APOD_Reddit/blob/develop/python_files/imgur_uploader.py).

Different attempts i have made to call the file include the below:

- `'image': b64encode(open(r'..\media\test.jpg', 'rb').read())`
- `'image': open(r'..\media\test.jpg', 'rb').read()`
- `'image': open('..\media\test.jpg', 'rb').read()`
- `'image': open('..\\media\\test.jpg', 'rb').read()`
- `'image': open(r'..\\media\\test.jpg', 'rb').read()`
- `'image': open('../\media/\test.jpg', 'rb').read()`

I have also tried to put the `test.jpg` photo into the same folder as the python script but unfortunately that did not work either.

Code I am using:

```
from base64 import b64encode
import json
import requests
import config



client_id = config.IMGUR_CLIENT_ID
# headers = ['Authorization'] = f'Client-ID {client_id}'
headers = {"Authorization": f'Client-ID {client_id}'}
api_key = config.IMGUR_CLIENT_SECRET
url = "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload.json"


# print(r'..\media\test.jpg')

j1 = requests.post(
    url, 
    headers = headers,
    data = {
        'key': api_key, 
        #'image': b64encode(open(r'..\media\test.jpg', 'rb').read()),
        'image': open(r'..\media\test.jpg', 'rb').read(),
        'type': 'base64',
        'name': 'test.jpg',
        'title': 'Picture no. 1'
    }
)
```

Picture of the file structure:

[image: File Structure]

Comment: first try with `/full/path/to/image.jpg` instead of using `../`. Next you should check `Current Working Folder` - `os.gecwd()` - because code may run in different folder then you expect and then `../` may lead to different folder then you expect. So it may try to load from folder which doesn't have images. And finally you can try `BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to get folder with script and later use `os.path.join(BASE, r'..\media\test.jpg')` to create full path to image. This problem and solution you should find in hundreds questions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: i appreciate the help but wasn't able to figure it out the way you are recommending, I ended up saving the photo to a fullpath'ed location and using that same location to pull from.

Comment: my method doesn't work because (as show your answer below) you ha problem in totally different place. You simply didn't have image on disk.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't figure this out so i ended up using the below code to save to a folder in my C drive, i don't need to store the variable anywhere since the file can be overwritten every time the code runs.

```
file_location = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, r'C:\temp\test.jpg')
```

Comment: I don't understand it - in question you tried to upload image but here you download image.   So your question was totally wrong. You couldn't upload file because you didn't have it.